# How to add autocomplete data into invoice dynamically

Tags: sql, pdo, autocomplete

I am looking for a way to add autocomplete data from my code to an "invoice" page automatically.  I want the user to be able to also click to add or remove each item(quickbooks style, with multiple form fields available, and adding dynamically) and in the long run, be able to drag elements to a certain position in the invoice.  All I am looking for now is this :

good : pseudocode on how to do this
best : basic working code to take off with.

This is what I have so far :

Page that calls the data :

```
<?php 

    require 'database.php';
    require 'results.php';

if(!empty($_GET['wid']))      { $wid = $_GET['wid'];  }
elseif(!empty($_POST['wid'])) { $wid = $_POST['wid']; }
else                         { $wid = null;         }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/engine.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Add Item to Workorder</h3>
                    </div>

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="additems.php" method="post">
                    <?php 
                    // Add Custom Call for values from prior page ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="wid" value="<?php echo htmlentities($wid); ?>">

                    <?php
                    //not required, but for get link purposes
                    if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search']!=''){
                        $search = $_POST['search'];
                        } elseif (isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search']!=''){
                        $search = $_GET['search'];
                        } else {
                        $search='';
                                }
                    //

                    echo"

                    <input type='text' class='search_input' name='search' id='search' placeholder='search' value='$search' autofocus>
                    <div id='search_output' class='search_output'>";
                    ?>
```

Page that retrieves results :

```
<?php
require_once"database.php";//connection to database
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search']){
    $search=$_POST['search'];
} elseif(isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search']){
    $search=$_GET['search'];
}

if(isset($search)){
    $search = '%' . strtr($search, ['%' => '\%', '_' => '\_']);
    $search = str_replace(" ", "%", $search);
    $search= "%$search%";
    $sql="select * from products where `model` LIKE ? OR `category` LIKE ? OR `description` LIKE ? OR `subcategory` LIKE ? LIMIT 50;";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute([$search, $search, $search, $search]);

//configure for your custom data dump to autocomplete
echo "
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered' width='100%'>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Model</th>
                          <th>Category</th>
                          <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      ";
    while($row = $statement->fetch()){
        $item=$row['model'];
        $title=$row['category'];
        $description=$row['description'];
        echo "  
                    <tr>
                    <td>
            <a href='?item=$item'>
            $item
            </td><td>
            $title
            </td><td>
            $description
            </a>
            </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
    //
}
```

Comment: You will need JQUERY and AJAX

Comment: I am using that for the autocomplete per someones suggestion, not very familiar with it(more towards php and sql).  Can you give an example of how I might do this?

Comment: AJAX and Javascript is the only way to do it .. give me some time I  will review your source code properly

Answer (score 0):

This code contains Javascript and AJAX code which is for making dynamic search from the input and displaying the sql results in the 'search_output'.

```
<input type='text' class='search_input' onkeyup="performSearch(this.value);" id='search' placeholder='search' value='$search' autofocus>
<div id='search_output' class='search_output'>";                    

<script>
    function performSearch(data) { 
       if (data.length > 0) { 
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() { 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("search_output").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }                 
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "YOURPHPFILENAME.php?search=" + data, true);
          xmlhttp.send();
       } 
    } 
</script>
```

Unfortunately for other Dynamic features you will need to learn JQUERY/AJAX and understand HTML DOM. There may be Third party API which may do this.